# How to open a contents of a div in a popup using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small div with less height because of that I have a long scrollbar for that.

I want to do something like if the user clicks on the div then the content of the div should open in a popup.

But if I apply popup to that div then it will be not visible on click as popup hides the div.

[image]

Above is the div with white background. As it has a long scrollbar I want to show the content of that div in a popup. How to pursue?

Comment: Kindly supply code or a demo

Comment: Did any of the answers work out for you?

Comment: yes i have posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what is this question about but generally speaking pop-ups are just divs with id/name/class set and 'display : none' option set in styles. Also somewhere in your code there is a function that makes it visible for some time like:

```
$('#yourDivId').toggle() or $('#yourDivId').css('display', 'block');
$('#yourDivId').css('display', 'none');
```

Also as noobed said you can use $('selector').hide(); $('selector').show();

Comment: jquery supports `$('selector').hide()` and `.show()`

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you might want to use [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

and the code goes as simple as:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

For more options on the dialog refer to the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use bootstrap Modal for popup to show your message.

   ```
   <div class="modal fade" id="">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
         </div>             
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
   </div><!-- /.modal -->
   ```
2. Write below code to show popup modal with your text.

   ```
   $('#divSelector').click(function(){
      var textToDisplay = $(this).val(); // This is for input boxes, if u want to show div contents use text()
       $('.modal-body').text(textToDisplay);
       $('#popup').modal('show');         
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I added an empty div `#divPopupMessage` and on click on the main div `#messagediv` i called the below jquery function

```
$(function () {
        $("#divPopupMessage").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Inbox",
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true

        });

        $('#messagediv').click(function () {
            $("#divPopupMessage").text($('#messagediv').text());
            $("#divPopupMessage").dialog("open");
        });
    });
```